# Como o Google vê um subdomínios?

Tags: google, seo, subdomínio, sitemap

Se eu tiver um site "meusite.com" e criar um subdominio "sub.meusite.com" vai ver como outro site ou como apenas o mesmo site ?

Comment: Porque o Google é o [olho que tudo vê](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_Providence). Ele sabe tudo sobre todos.

Comment: Depende. Você quer fazer [encaminhamento de um subdomínio para outro](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6072198?hl=pt-br) ou criar um site separado a partir de um subdomínio?

Comment: Se for proposital que o subdomínio seja um novo site, o google simplesmente indexá-lo-á como um site. Eu acho importante você saber manusear o [Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=pt-BR) para poder configurar o seus domínios de maneira apropriada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oficialmente cada subdomínio é um site diferente.
Na prática não é tão simples assim. Se você for penalizado por blackhat em um subdomínio é pouco provável que o domínio principal seja penalizado também, mas se o site principal for penalizado a queda do subdomínio é quase certa.

O mesmo se aplica a autoridade do domínio. Se a globo.com lançar um novo projeto asdfg.globo.com o Google verá esse novo site com mais otimismo do que se fosse um domínio recém registrado asdfg.com